# Is there a simple way to explain GPS resolution?

Tags: trigonometry, wave-equation

I had always assumed that GPS satellites were geo-synchronous, and that the process of resolving your location was simple trigonometry.

It turns out that GPS satellites are non-geo-synchronous - being in [a medium earth orbit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_Earth_orbit).

The [following description of the calculation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System#Fundamentals) states:

> GPS satellites transmit data continuously which contains their current time and position. A GPS receiver listens to multiple satellites and solves equations to determine the exact position of the receiver and its deviation from true time. At a minimum, four satellites must be in view of the receiver in order to compute four unknown quantities (three position coordinates and clock deviation from satellite time).

So then they [have another go at explaining it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System#User-satellite_geometry):

> Although usually not formed explicitly in the receiver processing, the conceptual TDOAs define the measurement geometry. Each TDOA corresponds to a hyperboloid of revolution. The line connecting the two satellites involved (and its extensions) forms the axis of the hyperboloid. The receiver is located at the point where three hyperboloids intersect.

Then they provide a picture:
[image]

Now it seems that my phone is doing all that.

My question is: **Is there a simple way to explain GPS resolution?** Something at the level of High School Physics, Calculus and Algebra.

Comment: You could ask the students to do a [triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation) on a plane using imprecise measurements (e.g. $\alpha = 45^\circ \pm 1^\circ$) and you will get an area instead of a point. You could also ask them to do triangulation on transparencies (saying precision is very important) and then align them all and show the results won't coincide. That's not exactly what's happening, because with GPS there's a lot more going on, but I would say it's a start.

Comment: One source of uncertainty is in the timing measurement. IIRC GPS uses [Gold sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_code) of period $1023=2^{10}-1$ constructed using the basic properties of character sums over the finite field $\Bbb{F}_{1024}$. Each satellite in the system has its unique signature sequence, so that a receiver will not mix the signals of distinct satellites. Those are broadcast at (IIRC) about 1Mhz, so the length of the radiowave of representing an individual bit of that sequence is 300 meters.

Comment: (cont'd) Engineers tell me that getting synchronized to that signal is possible downto one tenth of a chip - i.e. 30 meters (=100 ft). This places a bound on the resolution to the receiver's distance from a single satellite. It also explains why it is faster to calculate your position, if the receiver can assume that it has moved less than 300 km since the previous use. That entire 1023 bit signal has length 300 km, so a single satellite distance data is only known modulo an integer multiple of 300 km.

Comment: To make sure I meant that the *chip rate* is 1MHz. The carrier signal undoubtedly has a higher frequency. IANA telcomm engineer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The book ["Exploring Black holes: an introduction to general relativity"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/020138423X) contains a chapter with a project devoted to the GPS system. The book only uses basic Calculus and Algebra, but makes a few assumptions which can only be fully explained using the full theory of general relativity. But the necessary assumptions and physics are explained at a basic level in the book.

That particular chapter is based on two articles

[Carroll O. Alley, "Proper Time Experiments in Gravitational Fields with Atomic Clocks, Aircraft, and Laser Light Pulses"](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4613-3712-6_18)

and

[Neil Ashby,"Relativistic Effects in the Global Positioning System"](http://www.aapt.org/doorway/tgru/articles/ashbyarticle.pdf).